# Row-wise count in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Suppose I have 4 columns (Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, and Column 4). I want to calculate row-wise how many times 30 appears in the rows and create a new column **Count 30**. How can I do that in pandas?

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Count 30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 50 | 30 | 30 | 3 |
| 40 | 30 | 50 | 30 | 2 |

Comment: `df['Count 30'] = (df == 30).astype(int).sum(axis=1)` (modified from [the accepted answer](/a/29229653/15497888) of the now linked duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the original dataframe is `df` and looks like this

```
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4
0        30        50        30        30
1        40        30        50        30
```

Then one can use a custom lambda function as follows

```
df['Count 30'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().get(30, 0), axis=1)

[Out]:

   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4  Count 30
0        30        50        30        30         3
1        40        30        50        30         2
```

Another option would be using [`np.count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) as follows

```
import numpy as np

df['Count 30'] = np.count_nonzero(df == 30, axis=1)

   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4  Count 30
0        30        50        30        30         3
1        40        30        50        30         2
```